# How to avoid event handler get called when no namespace is defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces, jquery-events

Assume a bunch of event handler like this:

```
$('.foo').on('bar.foo', function(e) {...})
```

They are intended only get called for `bar.foo` events. Unfortunately they are also called for `bar` events, triggered by external plugins and libs I don't know.

The simplest approach would be:

```
$('.foo').on('bar.foo', function(e) {
  if (!e.namespace) return
  ...
})
```

But the problem is that there are a lot of event handlers. Is there any other possibility to prevent the calling of those event handlers for `bar.foo` when only `bar` is triggered?

Edit: Renaming the `bar` event is not a solution in this case.

Comment: If you don't want them to be triggered for other `bar` events, why not just use a different event name?

Comment: Because I can't change every time some external lib I don't now uses that name I also already use. This behavior of jQuery is some kind of annoying I think.

Comment: If I understand your question (needs better examples), you should not have `bar` events, if you also use a `bar` event namespace. It matches the first part.

Comment: I don't use `bar` events without the namespace. But other vendor stuff does it. The problem is I can't imagin all event name which might be used by some other vendor stuff. And it would make the idea of namespaces useless!

Comment: Use some prefix for event name to avoid conflict with others.

Comment: In your case this behavior seems useless but in most cases this is the intended behavior. E.g. if you want to have a click handler which you want to remove later but leave the other handlers intact.

Comment: Is this not what namespaces for? This jQuery stuff is such a silly lib :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event namespaces are mostly intended as helpers to easily unbind specific anonymous callbacks.

```
$( body ).on( 'click', function() {
    console.log( 'Default click on body' );
});

$( body ).on( 'click.myCustomPluginNamespace', function() {
    console.log( 'Custom plugin click on body' );
});

// On plugin cleanup, to leave the default binding intact.
$( body ).off( 'click.myCustomPluginNamespace' );
```

Without that you would need to save references to your custom listener functions, which is:

1. Tedious to write
2. Not very garbage collector friendly as those will still remain in memory when listener is unregistered.

Comment: Yes I know, but I was writing the last sentence when he did that :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

flec pointed that behavior of jQuery out (see comments):

> In your case this behavior seems useless but in most cases this is the intended behavior. E.g. if you want to have a click handler which you want to remove later but leave the other handlers intact.

So it seems I have to use the approach above `if (!e.namespace) return`. jQuery sucks at this point.